# Sharing a printer on Windows home network

Tags: windows, networking, printer

I have a home network, and I'm trying to share a printer connected to one of the PCs.  The wireless modem through which the internet comes through doesn't reach the entire house, so we have another router set up as well.

The modem is 192.168.1.1 (let's call this A) and the router is set up as 192.168.1.100 (let's call this B).  Subnet masks 255.255.255.0.

The printer is hooked up to a PC on B.  If my laptop is connected wirelessly to B, it can see the printer.  However, if it's connected to A, it doesn't show up in My Network Places.

How can I get it so that I can print to the printer regardless of whether the